# how to change the shape of rules that extracted from tree?

Tags: python, tree, extract, rules

I am using [`sklearn.tree.export_text`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html) to extract rules from a decision tree:

```
|--- sepal length (cm) <= 5.75
|   |--- petal width (cm) <= 0.70
|   |   |--- class: 0.0
|   |--- petal width (cm) > 0.70
|   |   |--- class: 1.0
|--- sepal length (cm) > 5.75
|   |--- petal length (cm) <= 4.75
|   |   |--- class: 1.0
```

How can I write every rule in just one line as

```
sepal length (cm) <= 5.75, petal width (cm) <= 0.70 -----> class: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
import re

tree = """
|--- sepal length (cm) <= 5.75
|   |--- petal width (cm) <= 0.70
|   |   |--- class: 0.0
|   |--- petal width (cm) > 0.70
|   |   |--- class: 1.0
|--- sepal length (cm) > 5.75
|   |--- petal length (cm) <= 4.75
|   |   |--- class: 1.0
"""

def format_rule(stack):
    rule = ", ".join(stack[:-1])
    clazz = stack[-1].replace(": ", " = ")
    return rule + " -> " + clazz

stack = []
result = []

for line in tree.split("\n"):
    if not line:
        continue

    match = re.fullmatch(r"((?:\|   )*)\|--- (.*)", line)
    depth = len(match.group(1)) // len(r"|   ")
    label = match.group(2)

    if len(stack) > depth:
        result.append(format_rule(stack))

    stack = stack[:depth]
    stack.append(label)

result.append(format_rule(stack))
print("\n".join(result))

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(result))
```

Output:

```
sepal length (cm) <= 5.75, petal width (cm) <= 0.70 -> class = 0.0
sepal length (cm) <= 5.75, petal width (cm) > 0.70 -> class = 1.0
sepal length (cm) > 5.75, petal length (cm) <= 4.75 -> class = 1.0
```

Comment: thank you so so much Androbin it is a fantastic answer :)

Comment: please can you help me how can i write these rules to text file

Comment: I'm sorry but also  i need  to change a small things in the rule shape ,put ( ->) sign befor class word and ( = )sign after class word.

Comment: thank u too much dear Androbin it works ,I try to apply the code to a set of trees (RF) I store the rules of trees in a variable and assign it to tree as follow model=RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'gini',n_estimators=5) clf=clf.fit(X_train, y_train) clf.estimators_ n= len(model.estimators_) for i in range (n): m=tree.export_text(model.estimators_[i],feature_names) import re tree =m...etc But this error is appeard 'depth = len(match.group(1)) // len(r"| ") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' ,so nothing print and the output file is empty

Comment: of course I will do that It is really an exact answer ,I dont work more with stack overflow so i dont know about that

Comment: when i assign the variable to tree as tree=m the error message occures ,but when i copy the content of the text that contains the rules  and put the signs ("""\) before the rules and (""") at the end the program is applied without errors

Comment: I believe sklearn.tree.export_text(...) returns the tree with a trailing newline, so there is an empty line that causes the issue. I have adapted the code accordingly.

Comment: thank u aloooot ,it works well . There is a small problem in the last rule the sign after class word is (:)instead of (=)

Comment: My mistake, the formatting issue should be fixed now :)

Comment: Its normal if the resulted rules just 6 lines for 100 estimators (trees )in random forest ensemble classifier??

Comment: really!!! that is means when i put n_estimator=100 ,just the rules of tree number 100 will extract ? even i use for statment as follow                                                                              for i in range (n):
    m= tree.export_text(model.estimators_[i],feature_names)                                                   hence (n) number of estimators (trees)

Comment: Are you using a RandomForestClassifier with a DecisionTreeClassifier as base estimator? Yes I'm

Comment: I believe you only keep the last tree. Are you computing the result in every loop iteration or just once after the loop? How are you trying to collect the results of all loop iterations? It seems like you are either overwriting 'm' or 'result'.

Comment: I try to write (m) to text file at every iteration        for i in range (n):
    print(tree.plot_tree(model.estimators_[i],filled=True))
    m= tree.export_text(model.estimators_[i],feature_names) f = open('m.txt', 'w+')
    f.write(str(m)) 
    f.close()

Comment: File open mode "w+" truncates the file before writing. If you want to append, use file open mode "a".

Comment: Yes ,your suggestion is nice I get the rules for all estimators .But I can't store them in a variable and assign it to (tree) to convert them automatically as a new format(one line for each rule) the variable (m) give me just the rules for one tree .What can I do ,help me please!!!

Comment: I tried to make m as a list m=[ ] ,the following erroe is occured .... for line in tree.split("\n"):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'